# Cannot send email using xamarin ios implementation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

trying to send an email calling the method below but I keep getting
  and the email ios form is not displayed.

> " Attempt to present MFMailComposeViewController: 0x1560e1a00    on
>   Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_PlatformRenderer: 0x157b5c180
>      whose  view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Any ideas of what I need to do to make it work?

```
     public void SendEmail()
     {
            string to="jo@gmail.com";
            string subject="Test";
            string body="This is a test email";

            if (MFMailComposeViewController.CanSendMail)
            {
                var mailComposeViewController = new MFMailComposeViewController();

                mailComposeViewController.SetToRecipients(new[] { to });
                mailComposeViewController.SetSubject(subject);
                mailComposeViewController.SetMessageBody(body, false);

                mailComposeViewController.Finished += (s, args) =>
                {
                    Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread
                    (
                        () => { args.Controller.DismissViewController(true, null); }
                    );
                };

                UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(mailComposeViewController, true, null);
            }           
    }
```

Comment: In what context are you defining `SendEmail`? (A custom Forms' renderer or a dependacy service?)

Comment: I just have an interface that is implemented in iOS project with a method send email.i am open to other suggestions

Comment: refer to this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136464/access-viewcontroller-in-dependencyservice-to-present-mfmailcomposeviewcontrolle

Comment: @ColeXia make it an answer and I will accept.many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should find the correct rootviewController on the top of the window.

Try this :

```
var rootController = ((AppDelegate)(UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate)).Window.RootViewController.ChildViewControllers[0].ChildViewControllers[1].ChildViewControllers[0];
```

And modify your last line of  code  to

```
var rootController = ((AppDelegate)(UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate)).Window.RootViewController.ChildViewControllers[0].ChildViewControllers[1].ChildViewControllers[0];
var navcontroller = rootController as UINavigationController;
if (navcontroller != null)
    rootController = navcontroller.VisibleViewController;
rootController.PresentViewController (controller, true, null);
```